# Formatting text to bold and inserting formula to get sum

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

Above is what the code below does.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long
    Dim k As Long
    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    With ws

        For i = 1 To 200
            If Left(.Cells(i, 1).Value, 2) = "HW" Then
                On Error Resume Next
                k = .Range(.Cells(i + 1, 1), .Cells(200, 1)).Find("HW").Row
                On Error GoTo 0
                If k <= i Then k = 200
                .Cells(i, 10).Value = Len(Cells((i + 2), 1).Value) - Len(Replace(Cells((i + 2), 1).Value, ",", "")) + 1
                .Cells(i, 11).Value = "SET"
                .Cells(i, 12).Resize(k - i).Value = .Cells(i, 1).Resize(k - i).Value
                .Cells((i + 1), 12).Resize(k - i).Value = .Cells((i + 1), 1).Resize(k - i).Value
                .Cells((i + 2), 12).Resize(k - i).Value = ws.Cells((i + 2), 1).Resize(k - i).Value
                .Cells((i + 3), 12).Resize(k - i).Value = ""
                .Cells((i + 4), 12).Resize(k - i).Value = "QTY"
                .Cells((i + 4), 13).Resize(k - i).Value = "TYPE"
                .Cells((i + 4), 15).Resize(k - i).Value = "LENGTH"
                .Cells((i + 4), 16).Resize(k - i).Value = "FINISH"
                .Cells((i + 4), 19).Resize(k - i).Value = "LIST"
                .Cells((i + 4), 20).Resize(k - i).Value = "NET"
                .Cells((i + 4), 21).Resize(k - i).Value = "MFG"
                .Cells((i + 4), 22).Resize(k - i).Value = "MODEL"

                .Cells((i + 5), 12).Resize(k - i).Value = .Cells((i + 3), 1).Resize(k - i).Value
                .Cells((i + 5), 13).Resize(k - i).Value = .Cells((i + 3), 2).Resize(k - i).Value
                .Cells((i + 5), 15).Resize(k - i).Value = .Cells((i + 3), 5).Resize(k - i).Value
                .Cells((i + 5), 16).Resize(k - i).Value = .Cells((i + 3), 6).Resize(k - i).Value
                .Cells((i + 5), 19).Resize(k - i).Value = .Cells((i + 3), 7).Resize(k - i).Value
                .Cells((i + 5), 20).Resize(k - i).Value = .Cells((i + 3), 8).Resize(k - i).Value
                .Cells((i + 5), 21).Resize(k - i).Value = .Cells((i + 3), 3).Resize(k - i).Value
                .Cells((i + 5), 22).Resize(k - i).Value = .Cells((i + 3), 4).Resize(k - i).Value

                i = k + 1
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

A couple problems. First I'm not sure why but for the second data output it is missing the # of doors, SET, and all the different hardware. It looks like it is skipping it?

Second problem is i do not know how to make my headings (QTY, TYPE, LENGTH, FINISH, LIST, NET, MFG, MODEL) bold using VBA code. I think i would use text.bold but i don't think i know how to word it correctly.I would also like to put a double line underneath them including column N but excluding Q and R.

Third I would like to sum my NET prices at the end of the NET column, but im not sure how to specify that cell. I would also like the cell to the right of it to divide the sum of the net by a specific cell.

Forth, I tried doing this,

```
"DOOR: " & ws.Cells((i + 2), 1).Resize(k - i).Value
```

This triggers an error because one is a string and the other is an integer. I thought i could use CStr(), but that does not work.

When all is coded correctly i would like it to look like this.

[image]

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would move all the title row into an Array.  Then you can just resize the area and assign the array.

As to your problems:

1) Math, when adding rows and refering to data that does not add the rows also there is a lot of math.  You were basically overwriting data as you went.

2) one way to format the bold is `Range.Font.Bold = True`.  With that the borders are similar `Range.Borders(XlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlDouble`.

3) Again Lots and Lots of math, Sometimes it is trial and error to get it correct.

4) You can't do that with a resize, it does not like it

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long
    Dim k As Long
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Dim ofst As Long
    Dim ttlArr() As String
    ttarr = Array("QTY", "TYPE", vbNullString, "LENGTH", "FINISH", vbNullString, vbNullString, "LIST", "NET", "MFG", "MODEL")
    ofst = 0
    With ws

        For i = 1 To 200
            If Left(.Cells(i, 1).Value, 2) = "HW" Then

                On Error Resume Next
                    k = .Range(.Cells(i + 1, 1), .Cells(200, 1)).Find("HW").Row
                On Error GoTo 0
                If k <= i Then k = .Cells(i, 1).End(xlDown).Row + 2
                .Cells(i + ofst, 11).Value = "SET"
                .Cells(i + ofst, 12).Resize(2).Value = .Cells(i, 1).Resize(2).Value
                If IsNumeric(.Cells((i + 2), 1).Value) Then
                    .Cells(i + ofst, 10).Value = Len("'" & Format(.Cells(i + 2, 1).Value, "#,##0")) - Len(Replace("'" & Format(.Cells(i + 2, 1).Value, "#,##0"), ",", "")) + 1
                    .Cells(i + ofst + 2, 12).Value = "Doors: " & Format(.Cells(i + 2, 1).Value, "#,##0")
                Else
                    .Cells(i + ofst, 10).Value = Len(.Cells(i + 2, 1).Value) - Len(Replace(.Cells(i + 2, 1).Value, ",", "")) + 1
                    .Cells(i + ofst + 2, 12).Value = "Doors: " & .Cells(i + 2, 1).Value
                End If
                .Cells(i + ofst + 4, 12).Resize(, UBound(ttarr) + 1).Value = ttarr
                .Cells(i + ofst + 4, 12).Resize(, UBound(ttarr) + 1).Font.Bold = True
                .Cells(i + ofst + 4, 12).Resize(, 5).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlDouble
                .Cells(i + ofst + 4, 19).Resize(, 4).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlDouble
                ofst = ofst + 2
                .Cells(i + ofst + 3, 12).Resize(k - i - 3).Value = .Cells(i + 3, 1).Resize(k - i - 3).Value
                .Cells(i + ofst + 3, 13).Resize(k - i - 3).Value = .Cells(i + 3, 2).Resize(k - i - 3).Value
                .Cells(i + ofst + 3, 15).Resize(k - i - 3).Value = .Cells(i + 3, 5).Resize(k - i - 3).Value
                .Cells(i + ofst + 3, 16).Resize(k - i - 3).Value = .Cells(i + 3, 6).Resize(k - i - 3).Value
                .Cells(i + ofst + 3, 19).Resize(k - i - 3).Value = .Cells(i + 3, 7).Resize(k - i - 3).Value
                .Cells(i + ofst + 3, 20).Resize(k - i - 3).Value = .Cells(i + 3, 8).Resize(k - i - 3).Value
                .Cells(i + ofst + 3, 21).Resize(k - i - 3).Value = .Cells(i + 3, 3).Resize(k - i - 3).Value
                .Cells(i + ofst + 3, 22).Resize(k - i - 3).Value = .Cells(i + 3, 4).Resize(k - i - 3).Value
                .Cells(i + ofst + k - i - 1, 20).Value = WorksheetFunction.Sum(.Cells(i + ofst + 3, 20).Resize(k - i - 4))
                ' Change the Range("H1") to your cell with the factor
                .Cells(i + ofst + k - i - 1, 21).Value = .Cells(i + ofst + k - i - 1, 20).Value / .Range("H1")
                .Cells(i + ofst - 2, 17).Value = .Cells(i + ofst + k - i - 1, 21).Value

                .Cells(i + ofst - 2, 18).Value = .Cells(i + ofst + k - i - 1, 21).Value * .Cells(i + ofst - 2, 10).Value
                i = k - 1
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I was thinking along the same lines; `.Cells(i + 4, 12).Resize(1, 11) = Array("QTY", "TYPE", vbNullString, _
                                                        "LENGTH", "FINISH", vbNullString, vbNullString, _
                                                        "LIST", "NET", "MFG", "MODEL")`

Comment: @Jeeped yeah, vbNullString is probably more accurate, I was being lazy.  The fun part was the math to get everything lining up properly.

Comment: @Geoff, you tried to edit my answer while I was doing an edit, it got rejected,  I see I may have the columns wrong I just copied what you had.  I added a few things and a better explanation.

Comment: @ Scott Craner Thanks so much . I'm trying to figure out the math at the moment but the line after ofst = ofst + 2 tell us in the active sheet select cell (3,12) and input the data from cell (3,1). Am i reading that right? Or wording it right?

Comment: Also I'm still trying to wrap my head around resize. I think i get it. .cell defines the top left position and resize defines the bottom right of the range?

Comment: @Geoff No it is sets the row number to i which changes with each loop 1,9,15 Plus the ofst which starts at 0 then gets increments by 2. This is to make up for the fact that you want to add 2 lines, 1 empty and 1 with the titles, every loop. Then the + 3 is because now the place we want to place the values, the is below the titles or 3 lines down from where they should go. A lot of variables to get the right row.

Comment: @Geoff Your understanding of resize is almost correct. You can go negative on the resize and go up and to the left. but it gets returns multiple cells. Offset moves the focus on from one cell to the next. End and then a direction is like hitting ctrl and then an arrow button.

Comment: @Scott Craner, The 3rd If statement doesn't seem to work properly. It doesn't input the string "Door " before the data.

Comment: One last thing, The last .Cells line is supposed to be multiplied by whatever value is in.Cells(i + ofst, 10).Value. I tried assigning Len(.Cells((i + 2), 1).Value) - Len(Replace(.Cells((i + 2), 1).Value, ",", "")) + 1 to variable NumDoor and it doesnt recognize the length of the source.

Comment: @Geoff I made some changes to the if statement as well as add the reference needed..  It should do that now.

Comment: @Scott Craner Thanks sooo much for all your help again. I never thought i would get that done in a day. I modified the code so it would output the data into the workbook i need it in. For some reason this MyWSTarget.Cells(i + ofst, 2).Value = Len("'" & Format(ws.Cells(i + 2, 1).Value, "#,##0")) - Len(Replace("'" & Format(ws.Cells(i + 2, 1).Value, "#,##0"), ",", "")) + 1 does not print on the first entry but does on the other 2, any ideas? See edited code above.

Comment: @Geoff I fixed my code to do it.  I added one line to the else statement in the if statement.

Comment: Thanks @ Scott Craner, Have a great weekend!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem with lost data had to do with finding the last occurrence of **HW*** when there was no terminating **HW*** to locate the end-of-record. Without seeing one or two **HW** records as a sample, this is the best I could figure out.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, k As Long, hw As Long, MX As Long

    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    With ws
        MX = 200   'maybe MX = .cells(rows.count, 1).end(xlup).row
        i = .Columns(1).Find(what:="HW*", after:=.Cells(MX, 1), lookat:=xlWhole).Row
        k = .Columns(1).FindNext(after:=.Cells(i, 1)).Row
        For hw = 1 To Application.CountIf(.Columns(1), "HW*")
            If k <= i Then k = MX
            Debug.Print i & ":" & k

            .Cells(i, 10) = UBound(Split(.Cells(i + 2, 1).Value, Chr(44))) + 1
            .Cells(i, 11).Value = "SET"
            .Cells(i, 12).Resize(k - i).Value = .Cells(i, 1).Resize(k - i).Value

            With .Cells(i + 4, 12)
                .Resize(1, 11) = Array("QTY", "TYPE", vbNullString, _
                                       "LENGTH", "FINISH", vbNullString, vbNullString, _
                                       "LIST", "NET", "MFG", "MODEL")
                With Union(.Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, 5), .Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, 5))
                    .Font.Bold = True
                    With .Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
                        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                        .ColorIndex = 0
                    End With
                End With
            End With


            .Cells((i + 5), 12).Resize(k - i).Value = .Cells((i + 3), 1).Resize(k - i).Value
            .Cells((i + 5), 13).Resize(k - i).Value = .Cells((i + 3), 2).Resize(k - i).Value
            .Cells((i + 5), 15).Resize(k - i).Value = .Cells((i + 3), 5).Resize(k - i).Value
            .Cells((i + 5), 16).Resize(k - i).Value = .Cells((i + 3), 6).Resize(k - i).Value
            .Cells((i + 5), 19).Resize(k - i).Value = .Cells((i + 3), 7).Resize(k - i).Value
            .Cells((i + 5), 20).Resize(k - i).Value = .Cells((i + 3), 8).Resize(k - i).Value
            .Cells((i + 5), 21).Resize(k - i).Value = .Cells((i + 3), 3).Resize(k - i).Value
            .Cells((i + 5), 22).Resize(k - i).Value = .Cells((i + 3), 4).Resize(k - i).Value

            i = .Columns(1).FindNext(after:=.Cells(k - 1, 1)).Row
            k = .Columns(1).FindNext(after:=.Cells(i, 1)).Row
        Next hw

    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim MyWSTarget As Worksheet
Dim i As Long
Dim k As Long
Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set MyWSTarget = Workbooks.Open("C:\MASTER_QT.xlsx").Sheets(1)
Dim ofst As Long
Dim ttlArr() As String
ttarr = Array("QTY", "TYPE", vbNullString, "LENGTH", "FINISH", vbNullString, vbNullString, "LIST", "NET", "MFG", "MODEL")
ofst = 17
With ws
    For i = 1 To 200
        If Left(ws.Cells(i, 1).Value, 2) = "HW" Then

            On Error Resume Next
                k = ws.Range(ws.Cells(i + 1, 1), ws.Cells(200, 1)).Find("HW").Row
            On Error GoTo 0
            If k <= i Then k = ws.Cells(i, 1).End(xlDown).Row + 2
            MyWSTarget.Cells(i + ofst, 3).Value = "SET"
            MyWSTarget.Cells(i + ofst, 4).Resize(2).Value = ws.Cells(i, 1).Resize(2).Value
            If IsNumeric(MyWSTarget.Cells((i + 2), 1).Value) Then
                MyWSTarget.Cells(i + ofst, 2).Value = Len("'" & Format(ws.Cells(i + 2, 1).Value, "#,##0")) - Len(Replace("'" & Format(ws.Cells(i + 2, 1).Value, "#,##0"), ",", "")) + 1
                MyWSTarget.Cells(i + ofst + 2, 4).Value = "Doors: " & Format(ws.Cells(i + 2, 1).Value, "#,##0")
            Else
                MyWSTarget.Cells(i + ofst + 2, 4).Value = "Doors: " & ws.Cells(i + 2, 1).Value
            End If
            MyWSTarget.Cells(i + ofst + 4, 3).Resize(, UBound(ttarr) + 1).Value = ttarr
            MyWSTarget.Cells(i + ofst + 4, 3).Resize(, UBound(ttarr) + 1).Font.Bold = True
            MyWSTarget.Cells(i + ofst + 4, 3).Resize(, 5).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlDouble
            MyWSTarget.Cells(i + ofst + 4, 10).Resize(, 4).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlDouble
            ofst = ofst + 2
            MyWSTarget.Cells(i + ofst + 3, 3).Resize(k - i - 3).Value = ws.Cells(i + 3, 1).Resize(k - i - 3).Value
            MyWSTarget.Cells(i + ofst + 3, 4).Resize(k - i - 3).Value = ws.Cells(i + 3, 2).Resize(k - i - 3).Value
            MyWSTarget.Cells(i + ofst + 3, 6).Resize(k - i - 3).Value = ws.Cells(i + 3, 5).Resize(k - i - 3).Value
            MyWSTarget.Cells(i + ofst + 3, 7).Resize(k - i - 3).Value = ws.Cells(i + 3, 6).Resize(k - i - 3).Value
            MyWSTarget.Cells(i + ofst + 3, 10).Resize(k - i - 3).Value = ws.Cells(i + 3, 7).Resize(k - i - 3).Value
            MyWSTarget.Cells(i + ofst + 3, 11).Resize(k - i - 3).Value = ws.Cells(i + 3, 8).Resize(k - i - 3).Value
            MyWSTarget.Cells(i + ofst + 3, 12).Resize(k - i - 3).Value = ws.Cells(i + 3, 3).Resize(k - i - 3).Value
            MyWSTarget.Cells(i + ofst + 3, 13).Resize(k - i - 3).Value = ws.Cells(i + 3, 4).Resize(k - i - 3).Value
            MyWSTarget.Cells(i + ofst + k - i - 1, 11).Value = WorksheetFunction.Sum(MyWSTarget.Cells(i + ofst + 3, 11).Resize(k - i - 4))
            ' Change the Range("H1") to your cell with the factor
            MyWSTarget.Cells(i + ofst + k - i - 1, 12).Value = MyWSTarget.Cells(i + ofst + k - i - 1, 11).Value / MyWSTarget.Range("L12")
            MyWSTarget.Cells(i + ofst - 2, 8).Value = MyWSTarget.Cells(i + ofst + k - i - 1, 12).Value

            MyWSTarget.Cells(i + ofst - 2, 9).Value = MyWSTarget.Cells(i + ofst + k - i - 1, 12).Value * MyWSTarget.Cells(i + ofst - 2, 2).Value
            i = k - 1
        End If
    Next i
```

End With
End Sub